# Aligning links on navbar

Tags: html, css

There are three links on navbar: Previous, Home and Next. If `.navbar` a `float: left` is done, all three gets aligned to left.If `.navbar` a `float: right` is done, all three gets aligned to right.  The problem is to align **Previous on left**, **Home on Center** and **Next on Right**. How can this be done with css?

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="back">Previous</a>
  <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: set the width of each link to 33%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very easy using `Flexbox`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
}

.home {text-align: center}
.next {text-align: right}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="back">Previous</a>
  <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">Next Next Next Next Next Next Next Next Next Next Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Using margins not ok if having dynamic content, because the middle one is only centered when the left and right one are of equal width.

Comment: @VXp I have no issues with different size content. What do you mean !?

Comment: Previous, with your example, if you changed the "Previous" text (or "Next") to something longer, you'd see that the middle one isn't centered anymore, because it's affected by the content length ot the other two, it wasn't even centered before for that matter, if being accurate. Of course not now, since I've changed it. :)

Comment: I'm talking about the `margin-*: auto` way, before I've edited your answer, just explaining why I did it.

Comment: Ohhh, i get it now. :) Thanks @VXp :)

Answer (score 2):

Set `text-align:center` for parent and then float only  **first** and **last** elements. This works even there are more anchors rather than the *Home* in the center.

```css
.navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align:center
    }

    .navbar a {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1%;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
 
    }
    
    .navbar a:first-of-type{float:left;}
    .navbar a:last-of-type{float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="back">Previous</a>
      <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Note that anchors should be `inline-block` not blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar a {
  width:31%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Working link  : https://codepen.io/sidhanshu28/pen/yEobga

Comment: If you don't want equal spacing, then you've to use float with this. I usually avoid float :)